# mciSendString, How to get the recorded buffer?

Tags: windows, audio, desktop-application, audio-recording, mci

I'm creating a recorder using MCI through the DllImport of winmm.dll: mciSendString.

I am able to record and save it. I would like to do some processing on it before saving but I did not find any proper way, method, trick to get the buffer during the recording(again, without saving to a WAV file first)?

Any idea?

```
mciSendString("open new type waveaudio alias recsound", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
mciSendString("record recsound", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
//Would like to get the buffer here
mciSendString("pause recsound", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
//or here
```

Comment: mciSendString() is entirely too simplistic to do this.  Nothing wrong with just opening the file, it will be very, very fast since all file data is still in memory.  You can complicate your life with, say, the NAudio library, WaveIn class.

Comment: I am testing NAudio and Wavein but hoped I could avoid using them.